# How do I bind UserControl to GridView while grouping?

Tags: xaml, gridview, binding, windows-8

I want to Bind UserControl in the ItemTemplate section of the GridView.

UserControl contains nothing but  with decorated text..

I had been using Collection which consisted of  and was binding Content directly within ItemTemplate within the main xaml page, which was easy.

But now my collection is changed to .. How do I bind now?

Comment: your question seems a bit unclear, did you have markup included that wasn't rendered correctly.  "consisted of ??" and "changed to ??"

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.. I had been using a collection which was <String header, String Content> which was working great..  But now my collection is changed to <String header, UserControl u1>.. How to bind usercontrol as an item template in the grid?

Comment: perhaps you can add some sample code to your question? Are you saying the GridView ItemsSource is a collection that includes a UserControl in the ViewModel?

Comment: Exactly.. Before I was having Content as string which i was easily binding it <TextBlock Padding="5,5,5,5" Text="{Binding Content}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}" Foreground="Chocolate" TextWrapping="Wrap" /> in the xaml page which was working fine.. But since now Content is not text but UserControl how do I bind?

Comment: As Jim is saying, please EDIT your post to include exactly what you are trying to do. Please ask the question with as much detail as you can possible provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put `UserControl`s in the model (i.e. your collection). They belong in the view (i.e. your XAML page).

I'm guessing you replaced the `String` you used originally with a `UserControl` because you want to use a different `UserControl` for different items. Take a look at [`ItemTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx). You can bind it to a `DataTemplateSelector` inside which you can decide which template to use based on the individual item. You can now have a custom class for the Content and a property inside it to select the `UserControl` based on it.

Comment: Damir: Exactly.. I want to do exactly that.. I've been trying to use DatatemplateSelector as u suggested.. But since I am new to windows 8 unable to accomplish the task.. Can u give me a small example?